# while loop not closing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner at python. I am trying to create a program and a part of it requires users to input coordinates then store them in a dictionary. I want it to stop asking for input once the user writes 'END'. However, when I run this particular piece of code, it doesn't close when you enter END.

---

```
dict_coord = {} #empty dictionary for coordinates users input
coord_no = 0
coord_no += 1
coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
dict_coord[coord_no] = coord

while coord != 'END':
    coord_no += 1
    coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
    dict_coord[coord_no] = coord
```

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```py
dict_coord = {} #empty dictionary for coordinates users input
coord_no = 0

while True:
    coord_no += 1
    userInput = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no))
    if userInput == "END":
        break
    dict_coord[coord_no] = userInput.split(',')
```

Answer (score 3):

`.split()` returns an array, so you need to refer to the first element in array in your condition as shown here:

```
dict_coord = {} #empty dictionary for coordinates users input
coord_no = 0
coord_no += 1
coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
dict_coord[coord_no] = coord

while coord[0] != 'END':
    coord_no += 1
    coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
    dict_coord[coord_no] = coord
```

Answer (score 0):

Split returns a list, so it will never be equal to `'END'` (a string).

```
print("END".split(",") == "END") # False
print("END".split(",") == ["END"]) # True
```

Comment: Good answer. Could be better if you pointed out the user's problem (using the if statement along with a break). This might not help the OP.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani no, if statement with break is not necessary. If the while condition is not met the loop will be exited just the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can just say break when the user enters end. So it could look something like this:

```
while True:
    coord_no += 1
    coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
    dict_coord[coord_no] = coord
    if coord == "END":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to using `break` Like this;

```
dict_coord = {} #empty dictionary for coordinates users input
coord_no = 0
coord_no += 1
coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
dict_coord[coord_no] = coord
    
while True:
    coord_no += 1
    coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
    print(coord)
    dict_coord[coord_no] = coord
    if "END" in coord or "end" in coord: #END and end is different for python '==' and 'in' syntax.
        break #if end in coord, break.
```

Answer (score -1):

you check for coord!=['end'].
the part you forgot was that you have to check for parsed strings when using parsed strings for arguments.
the fixed code is

```
dict_coord = {} #empty dictionary for coordinates users input
  coord_no = 0
   coord_no += 1
   coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
   dict_coord[coord_no] = coord

   while coord != ['end']: 
   coord_no += 1
   coord = input('Enter coordinate {}: '.format(coord_no)).split(',')
   dict_coord[coord_no] = coord
   print(coord)
   print(coord!=['end'])
```

Comment: That's not fixed, that's broken. The original stored 2-element lists in dict_coord, your code stores unparsed strings. Also please don't just post "fixed" code, *explain* what your code does better than the original.

Comment: sorry i was trying to get the loop working i will try to fix the rest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).